# No dejar borrar item en BD, si existe una relación

Tags: php, sql

Mi objetivo es tratar de que si un item de mi primer tabla tiene la clave foranea que seria un GENERO, no me deje borrar en mi segunda tabla ese GENERO, para esto hago uan consuta SQL pero me sigue tirando el error de que no puedo borrar mi clave foranea, alguien tiene idea de que en me puedo estar equivocando? Aca voy a dejar mi consulta de SQL y mi funcion de delete para eliminarlo. Si el genero no esta siendo utilizado en la otra tabla me deja borrarlo normalmente...

Aclaracion: Tengo las tablas entrelazadas por Genero_ID

```
Esta funcion es un contador en la base de datos a ver si algún genero esta siendo utilizado. 

function contadorCategoria($Genero_ID){
    $sentencia = $this->db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM generos c JOIN juegos l ON c.Genero_ID = l.Genero_ID LIKE ? GROUP BY c.Genero");
    $sentencia->execute(array($Genero_ID));
    $contador = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $contador;
}




Funcion que hace el delete segun si el contador esta null o no... 
function deleteGEN($Genero_ID){
$this->userHelper->checkLoggedIn();
$contador = $this->modelGenero->contadorCategoria($Genero_ID);
if ($contador == NULL){
$this->modelGenero->DeleteGeneroByIDGen($Genero_ID);
header("Location: " . BASE_URL);}
else {header("Location: " . BASE_URL);}}
```

Mis tablas se llaman juegos y generos.

Comment: ¿puedes poner el error exacto que te da al intentarlo?  Seguramente primero deberias borrar lo que tengas en **juegos** con ese Genero_ID para que después te permita borrarlo en **generos**, pues debes tener una relación entre esas tablas de integridad referencial de algun tipo (que no has dicho en la pregunta de forma exacta tampoco, pues hay varios).

Comment: El error es de que no puedo borrar mi clave foranea (La tengo en restrict) por que esta en la otra tabla como dije en el texto. Seguro me exprese mal.. yo lo que quiero es que si existe/esta siendo utilizado ese genero en la otra tabla me reedireccione a mi "home" si no existe que proceda a borrarlo.

Comment: Pues haz la consulta en **juegos** sobre ese `Genero_ID` y tal como tu has dicho, pones en un condicional que si existe/esta siendo utilizado ese genero en **juegos** te reedireccione a tu "home", y si no existe que proceda a borrarlo.  No se si me explico.  Creo que es lo que has dicho tu mismo.

Comment: Ese es mi problema es que lo tengo en mente, pero no se me ocurre como hacer la consulta.

Comment: supongo que tienes un modelo para juegos, por ejemplo $this->modeloJuegos, y dentro deberías tener una función que haga un `SELECT count(*) FROM juegos WHERE Genero_ID = $Genero_ID` donde `$Genero_ID` sea un parámetro que recibe. Entonces puedes hacer algo así como `$contajeJuegos = $this->modeloJuegos->porGeneroID($Genero_ID);` para después hacer el condicional así: `if ($contajeJuegos > 0) { // lo mandas al home con un header location} else { // lo borras con el código que ya tienes)}`... ¿ahora si me entiendes?  ¿o me equivoco en algo y no te he entendido bien?

Comment: esa consulta no esta bien...  Esto: ON c.Genero_ID = l.Genero_ID LIKE ?  esta mal.. y para saber cuantos generos estan siendo usados, si pasas el id, no necesitas nada de eso, alcanza con contar ese id en la tabla juegos...

Comment: @Masterguru consulte como me pusiste y me sigue sin funcionar, directamente no me borra ninguna.

Comment: @gbianchi y como seria eso? El ID que le paso es propio del genero no del juego

Comment: exacatmante como te digo masteguru...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es algo así, más o menos como decia en los comentarios:

```
function contadorCategoriaenJuegos($Genero_ID){
    $sentencia = $this->db->prepare("SELECT count(*) as contaje FROM juegos WHERE Genero_ID = :Genero_ID");
    $sentencia->execute(['Genero_ID' => $Genero_ID]);
    $contador = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $contador->contaje;
}

function deleteGEN($Genero_ID){
    $this->userHelper->checkLoggedIn();
    $contador = $this->contadorCategoriaenJuegos($Genero_ID);
    if ($contador > 0){
        header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
    } else {
        $this->modelGenero->DeleteGeneroByIDGen($Genero_ID);
        header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

Prueba a ver si da algun error de sintaxis o funciona bien.

### Cambios realizados

- Se ha cambiado la consulta pues lo único importante es saber si el valor de la variable `$Genero_ID` se está usando en la tabla **juegos**:

```
function contadorCategoriaenJuegos($Genero_ID){
    $sentencia = $this->db->prepare("SELECT count(*) as contaje FROM juegos WHERE Genero_ID = :Genero_ID");
    $sentencia->execute(['Genero_ID' => $Genero_ID]);
    $contador = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $contador->contaje;
}
```

y después se ha modificado el ligeramente la otra función para recibir ese resultado en la variable $contador, la cual puede valer 0 (que significa que no hay coincidencias en la tabla juegos) o un valor positivo (que indica la cantidad de veces que se usa en la tabla juegos), para luego hacer la redirección o la supresión del registro en la tabla `generos`:

```
function deleteGEN($Genero_ID){
    $this->userHelper->checkLoggedIn();
    $contador = $this->contadorCategoriaenJuegos($Genero_ID);
    if ($contador > 0){
        header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
    } else {
        $this->modelGenero->DeleteGeneroByIDGen($Genero_ID);
        header("Location: " . BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto... muchas gracias guru!! Abrazo grande... tendré que repasar mas SQL. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, he ampliado la explicación ahora que dices que ya te funciona bien. Saludos!